# How to add a UserControl which is in a Folder in Project to ToolBox

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm working on a Windows Forms project in *Visual Studio 2012*.

In the solution of the project, I created a new Folder named `userControls` and added to it a user-control (`UserControl1`).

Here is the tree view of the solution:

[image]

**How can I access the `UserControl` in that folder from the `ToolBox`?**

Rebuilding the Solution and restarting Visual Studio didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Try this: After closing Visual Studio, delete `bin` and `obj` folder. Also go to `%userprofile%\appdata\local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ProjectAssemblies` and delete all folders.

Comment: @RezaAghaei That works, Thank you!

Comment: @RezaAghaei btw, you can add it as answer, and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User controls which are in the current project will be added to toolbox automatically after a successful build and you don't need to perform additional tasks to do so.

Such problems which the toolbox not being populated with new user controls, are usually build error or designer errors. To solve the problem you can perform these tasks:

- Close Visual studio
- Delete Visual Studio designer cached files. To do so, go to below path and delete all folders:

  ```
  %userprofile%\appdata\local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\Proj‌​ectAssemblies
  ```
- Delete `bin` and `obj` folder of your projects.
- Open Visual Studio again and build solution.

Answer (score 0):

1.You can add this to you Toolbox using

```
Toolbox -> right click -> Choose Items -> Browse
```

Select your assembly with the `UserControl`.

2.Build the entire solution. After that, your `UserControl` should appear in the `toolbox`.

Comment: its VS2012, right-clicking on ToolBox doesn't have this option, rather it gives me those: `Dock`, `Float`, `Auto Hide`, `Hide`, `Docked as Tabbed Document`

Comment: @mww Controls which are in the current project will be added to toolbox automatically. Usually such problems are build/designer errors.